# How did conda install command choose os platform and python version when installing a package

Tags: python, conda

I will  install a `future` package in a conda environment.And the python version of enviroment is 2.7(32-bit).
[image]

Why conda choose the `py36 future` package not `py27 future` package .
And how did conda choose `Windows x86_64 (64-bit)` or `Windows x86 (32-bit)`.

I change the directory and run the python --version again.
[image]

Comment: Try changing your directory and type `python --version` again. What does it say?

Comment: @ Mike Müller ,which directory  i will choose?

Comment: Any other directory.

Comment: @ Mike Müller.  i change the directory and run the command again.The result showed above .

Comment: What does `where python` say?